# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [krvrdgpm_getpdbmap:2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Tags: oracle, java-8, oracle12c, ojdbc

Oracle vm details:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html
Name:Database App Development VM
Ojdbc8 driver

Getting ORA-00600 error while start the Logminer and run select query on the logminer  session.

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [krvrdgpm_getpdbmap:2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:747)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementProxy.executeQuery(PreparedStatementProxy.java:52)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.executeQuery(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java)
>       at com.impetus.cdc.oracle.OracleCDCGenerator.generateRecords(OracleCDCGenerator.java:649)
>       at com.impetus.cdc.oracle.OracleCDCGenerator.lambda$startGeneration$2(OracleCDCGenerator.java:588)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [krvrdgpm_getpdbmap:2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
>       ... 23 common frames omitted

Comment: Very hard to help with Ora-00600 errors. Depending on query being executed, Platform, Oracle version and Patch level. 
Look up the error in the alert.log and corresponding trace file and search Oracle suppprt.

Comment: This issue seemed to be fixed in 12.1.0.2. Check if it is possible to upgrade your database to 12.1.0.2 or 12.2.